# Authorize Logic App Outlook API Connection to shared mailbox

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App with a trigger called "when an email arrives".
The way I know how to connect the email to the Logic App is to edit the [connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx57w.png) to authorize it to my mailbox.

What I want to do is monitor a shared mailbox in which I have full permission. How can I authorize/make the trigger listen to this mailbox if it doesn't have a password? I saw another Logic App that was successfully connected to a shared mailbox but I don't know how it was done. **How can you connect to it and use this same trigger?**

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trigger "[when a new mail arrives at shared mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#when-a-new-email-arrives-in-a-shared-mailbox-(v2))" directly instead of "when an email arrives" trigger. Like below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I was looking for is to use "when an email arrives". I think it is not possible to use what I was looking for unless the shared mailbox is modified-licensed to have a password.